# Creating C function blocks in scilab 5.5.2

Tags: c, scilab

I have been using scilab version 5.5.2 (64 bit) under Windows 7 (64 bit).
For current project I need to be able to create xcos blocks which behavior
is prescribed by my own C language source code. I have found following
excellent tutorial [Tutorial Creating a C Function Block in Scicos](https://www.scicos.org/ScicosCBlockTutorial.pdf).

At first I have installed the MinGw toolbox 0.9.3. The installation seems
to be successful because the function haveacompiler returns true. Then I
have written the source code according to the above mentioned tutorial

```
// This is the computational function for a scicos model block.
// The model is of a variable-gain integrator with hard high and low limits.

    #include "c:\Program Files\scilab-5.5.2\modules\scicos_blocks\includes\scicos_block4.h"
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    #define r_IN(n, i)  ((GetRealInPortPtrs(blk, n+1))[(i)])
    #define r_OUT(n, i) ((GetRealOutPortPtrs(blk, n+1))[(i)])
    
    // parameters
    #define Lhi (GetRparPtrs(blk)[0])   // integrator high limit
    #define Llo (GetRparPtrs(blk)[1])   // integrator low limit
    
    // inputs
    #define in  (r_IN(0,0)) // integrator input
    #define gainp   (r_IN(1,0)) // integrator gain when x > 0
    #define gainn   (r_IN(2,0)) // integrator gain when x <= 0
    
    // states
    #define X   (GetState(blk)[0])  // integrator state
    #define Xdot    (GetDerState(blk)[0])   // derivative of the integrator output
    
    // outputs
    #define out (r_OUT(0,0))    // integrator output
    #define Igain   (r_OUT(1,0))    // integrator gain
    
    // other constants
    #define surf0   (GetGPtrs(blk)[0])
    #define surf1   (GetGPtrs(blk)[1])
    #define surf2   (GetGPtrs(blk)[2])
    #define mode0   (GetModePtrs(blk)[0])
    
    // if X is greater than Lhi, then mode is 1
    // if X is between Lhi and zero, then mode is 2
    // if X is between zero and Llo, then mode is 3
    // if X is less than Llo, then mode is 4
    #define mode_xhzl   1
    #define mode_hxzl   2
    #define mode_hzxl   3
    #define mode_hzlx   4
    
    void lim_int(scicos_block *blk, int flag)
    {
        double gain = 0;
    
        switch(flag)
        {
            case 0:
                // compute the derivative of the continuous time state
                if((mode0 == mode_xhzl && in < 0) || mode0 == mode_hxzl)
                    gain = gainp;
                else if((mode0 == mode_hzlx && in > 0) || mode0 == mode_hzxl)
                    gain = gainn;
                Xdot = gain*in;
            break;
    
            case 1:
                // compute the outputs of the block
                if(X >=Lhi || X <= Llo)
                    Igain = 0;
                else if (X > 0)
                    Igain = gainp;
                else
                    Igain = gainn;
                out = X;
            break;
    
            case 9:
                // compute zero crossing surfaces and set modes
                surf0 = X - Lhi;
                surf1 = X;
                surf2 = X - Llo;
    
                if(get_phase_simulation() == 1)
                {
                    if(surf0 >= 0)
                        mode0 = mode_xhzl;
                    else if(surf2 <= 0)
                        mode0 = mode_hzlx;
                    else if(surf1 > 0)
                        mode0 = mode_hxzl;
                    else
                        mode0 = mode_hzxl;
                }
            break;
        }
    }
```

After that I have called the function `ilib_for_link` with following
arguments `ilib_for_link('lim_int','lim_int_comp.c',[],"c")`

The function returns following output:

```
ilib_for_link('lim_int','lim_int_comp.c',[],"c")
   Generate a loader file
   Generate a Makefile
   Running the Makefile
   Compilation of lim_int_comp.obj
   Building shared library (be patient)
 
!------------- Compile file lim_int_comp.c --------------                                !
!                                                                                        !
!x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -c -DWIN32 -D_MSC_VER -DSTRICT -DFORDLL -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB!
!     ~1.2/libs/MALLOC/includes" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/core/includes" -I"C:/P!
!     ROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/api_scilab/includes" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/c!
!     all_scilab/includes" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/output_stream/includes" -I"C!
!     :/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/jvm/includes" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/local!
!     ization/includes" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/dynamic_link/includes" -I"C:/PR!
!     OGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/mexlib/includes" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/time/i!
!     ncludes" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/modules/windows_tools/includes" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/S!
!     CILAB~1.2/libs/f2c" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB~1.2/libs/hashtable" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/SCILAB!
!     ~1.2/libs/intl" -m64   lim_int_comp.c                                              !
!                                                                                        !
!lim_int_comp.c: In function 'lim_int':                                                  !
!                                                                                        !
!lim_int_comp.c:76:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_phase_simulation' [-!
!     Wimplicit-function-declaration]                                                    !
!                                                                                        !
!    if(get_phase_simulation() == 1)                                                     !
!                                                                                        !
!       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                             !
!                                                                                        !
!------------- Link files --------------                                                 !
!                                                                                        !
!x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe --shared lim_int_comp.o  -L"c:\cygwin64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\li!
!     b" -LC:\Users\Stepan\AppData\Roaming\Scilab\scilab-5.5.2\mingwlib_x64 -lstdc++ -lgf!
!     ortran -lMALLOC -lblasplus -lf2c -llapack -lcore -lcore_f -lintersci -loutput_strea!
!     m -ldynamic_link -linteger -loptimization_f -ljvm -lscilocalization -lintl -llinpac!
!     k_f -lcall_scilab -ltime -lapi_scilab -lscilab_windows -lscicos -lscicos_blocks -ls!
!     cicos_blocks_f -lscicos_f -o liblim_int.dll  -Wl,--out-implib=liblim_int.a -Wl,--ex!
!     port-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl                                      !
!                                                                                        !
!x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wl'; did you mean !
!     '-W'?                                                                              !
!                                                                                        !
!Makelib:102: recipe for target 'liblim_int.dll' failed                                  !
!                                                                                        !
!make: *** [liblim_int.dll] Error 1                                                      !
 !--error 10000 
ilib_compile: Error while executing Makelib.
at line      25 of function dlwCompile called by :  
at line      51 of function ilib_compile called by :  
at line      94 of function ilib_for_link called by :  
ilib_for_link('lim_int','lim_int_comp.c',[],"c")
```

It seems to me that the problem is that prototype for get_phase_simulation function is
missing. Has anybody already encountered this problem? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error is not due to the missing prototype (just a warning) but to the -Wl argument of x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe

Comment: Thank you. I haven't noticed this error message. Do you know where the problem could be?